# How to read data from generic ethernetIP device(Ingersoll QCX) having EDS file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ethernet

I am using pylogix library to read/write data from a generic ethernetIP device.
I have uploaded eds file into device but I dont know how to fetch data using pylogix library.
So far I am able to only connect to device and getting device info only.
Device is sending data in bytes.
I am trying to know tag names to be used but I am not sure how to use pylogix library in this case and getting empty object after using GetTagList().
EDS file link and details given on below link
Device details[Link](https://irtoolhelp.ingersollrand.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044514533-Setting-up-Ethernet-IP-on-INSIGHTqc)

I am able to connect with the device and also getting device details
device is sending data in bytes and i want to read this data but not able to read it
Below code giving me device details but not able to read incoming bytes and getting 'None'

```
import time
from pylogix import PLC

with PLC() as comm:
comm.IPAddress = '192.168.0.103'
# ret = comm.Read(tag:Any,count: int = 1,  datatype: Any | None = None) 
#getting error here
print(comm.GetDeviceProperties())
tags = comm.GetTagList()
print(tags)
read = True
while read:
    try:
        ret = comm.Read('Assem112')
        print(ret.Value)
        # print(ret.Value)
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exiting')
        read = False
```

Comment: I dont think pylogix has such functionality.  you need an ethernet/IP PLC to connect to the device and then Pylogix could read and write tags on that PLC.